# Deallocated Instance in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uicollectionview

I have a class called `SLCollectionViewModel` that, if initiated, will fetch the latest entry with Core Data. So far there is no problem with the initial view. The Collection View will display the visible entries correctly (and also shows them in log).

But the problem occurs when I try to scroll the view, or try to call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` explicitly. The error log is:

`-[_PFArray retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8de9ab0`

I think my `self.viewModel` object is deallocated somewhere, but I can’t pinpoint what’s wrong with my approach. Here is my `- (void)viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.viewModel = [SLCollectionViewModel new];

  [self.collectionView reloadData];

}
```

And here is my `SLCollectionViewModel` class:

```
- (instancetype) init {

  self = [super init];
  if(!self) return nil;

  _managedObjectContext = [[SLCoreDataStack defaultStack] managedObjectContext];

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                      entityForName:@"SLPost"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
  // The _posts in an NSArray that saves all my NSManageObject
  // which will be used to populate the collection view.
  _posts = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                error:nil];

  return self;
}
```

Comment: How is the `@property` for `self.viewModel` declared?

Comment: It’s `@property (nonatomic, strong) SLCollectionViewModel *viewModel;`

Comment: When the program halts and activates the debugger what is the output `po`ing the memory address it says was deallocated? i.e. from your original question `po 0x8de9ab0`.  
Also out of interest is the crash consistent, with the same error message each time?

Comment: The crash is consistent, with the same error, but different address. The output for `po 0x90c0000` is `-[_PFArray respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x90c0000
151781376`

Comment: Turn on [`NSZombie`s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and then update your answer with the results

Comment: I think I’ve enabled NSZombie in Diagnostic tab. But there is no differences with the result shown in log. Do I have to use **Instruments** for this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but see what it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is my own mistake for not creating the property properly. In my `SLCollectionViewModel`, the `@property` for `NSArray *posts` should use `retain` instead of `assign`.

Before:
`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray *posts;`

After:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *posts;`